# Export, Publish or Deploy Power View to SharePoint on Premise NOT AVAILABLE ?!

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, excel-2013, powerview

I have just finished working on a Power View Report in Excel 2013,
 so i thought ok, now that this is done I can simply Publish it to my SharePoint Power View Gallery, must be pretty simple right, after all It could only be intuitively assumed that this Option is available.

But guess what i found THERE is no way of exporting it to SharePoint on Premise (not talking about Office 365)

All i want to do as a User, after having paid Microsoft Tons of Money, is to have my Power View Report i have worked on for so Long in Excel Published (Deployed) on my SharePoint Power View Gallery, it is really as simple as that, but there seems to be no way for it.
 Still not believing it, after having read half the Pages on Google, without finding anything i have decided to turn to you my Friends.

Is the only way of having a Power View Report on my SharePoint - Power View Gallery really only by creating it in SharePoint - in other words - do i have tu build everything on SharePoint with all the limitations even though it seems so unbelievably intuitive for there to be an Option to Export my Power View Excel 2013 Sheet to SharePoint ?

Thanks a lot for your answers in Advance!

Comment: To save your Power View report to your SharePoint Power Pivot gallery, you [save the entire Excel workbook](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee637435.aspx) to that location rather than a single Power View report. Did you try this and encounter difficulties?

Comment: This functionality is available in on-premise installations of SharePoint, assuming you have your SP addins installed (Excel and PP services IIRC) and was working as of 2011 for me.

Comment: @mmarie - thanks for the answer, no i do not have any difficulties doing that, but i much rather had it stored the way it is supposed to be and the way it is serves me better.

Comment: @billinkc Yes, that is true, worked for me on SharePoint 2010 too, it's just something that changed since SharePoint 2013 i guess